# I'm trying to separate the name of the song and the artist

Tags: java, android, text

I'm trying to separate the name of the song and the artist
I have a content textview as "SongName_Artist" how can I split SongsName and Artist into 2 textview

Comment: Is your question answered or is there anything I can make clearer for you?

Answer (score 1):

Get your layout (you'll need an ID on it):

```
mLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
```

Find your content text:

```
contentTextView = findViewById(R.id.contentTextView);
String contentText = contentTextView.getText().toString();
```

Create `TextView` for song and artist:

```
TextView songTextView = new TextView(this);
TextView artistTextView = new TextView(this);
songTextView.setText(contentText.split("_")[0]);
artistTextView.setText(contentText.split("_")[1]);
```

Add them to layout:

```
mLayout.addView(songTextView);
mLayout.addView(artistTextView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has a built in split function that will work in this case.  Below is what the java code should look like:

```
    String whole = "Song_Artist";
    String[] pieces = whole.split("_");
    String song = pieces[0]; //everything before the _
    String artist = pieces[1]; //everything after the _
```

Now that you have the string broken down you can go ahead and use setText to set the textViews as desired.

Comment: What if my string is String []?

Comment: String[] is an array of strings.  To access each value in that array we have to reference it.  That is why we set the song equal to pieces[0], the first value in the array, and the artist equal to pieces[1], the second value in the array.  Keep in mind that arrays always start at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.split() method to separate the string.

```
 String str = "soniye_falak";
   String[] parts = string.split("_");
    String song = parts[0]; // soniye
    String artist = parts[1]  //falak
```

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array. If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is split between each character. Note: The split() method does not change the original string.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use split function of string
Eg (“your_string”).split(“_”) and collect the returning value
code goes here:

```
String song_artist = "S_A";
System.out.println(song_artist.split("_"));
String[] temp = song_artist.split("_");
    for(int i=0; i<temp.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(temp[i]);
    }
```